# node.js Async : crop image and upload to server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous, gm

I want to crop an image into various sizes and upload them to AWS S3. Cropping sizes are stored in an array.

I am using `async` waterfall and `series` method to achieve this.

```
async.each(crop_sizes,function (result,cb) {

            async.waterfall([
                /*
                 * Crop the images to specific size
                 */
                function (callback) {
                    gm(path)
                        .resize(result.width,result.height,'^')
                        .stream(function (err,buffer) {
                            console.log('cropped')
                            callback(null,{'buffer':buffer,'filename':filename,'s3':s3});
                        });
                },
                function (output,callback) {
                    var params ={
                        Bucket:'mybucket',
                        Key:'artwork-croppedimages/'+result.folder+output.filename,
                        Body:output.buffer
                    }

                    var options ={
                        partSize: 5242880, queueSize: 1
                    };

                    s3.upload(params,options,function(err, data) {
                        console.log("upload");

                        callback();
                    });
                }

            ],function (err,result) {
                console.log("one iteration completed");
                cb();
            });
        },function (err,result) {
            console.log("All upload complete");
        });
```

This is how the code should execute:

Repeat steps 1 and 2 in `async.each`.

1. Crop the image.
2. Upload the cropped image to AWS S3.

But it fails while uploading large sized images. This is the output I get:

```
cropped
cropped
cropped
cropped
cropped
cropped
cropped
cropped
cropped
cropped
cropped
cropped
upload
one iteration completed
upload
one iteration completed
upload
one iteration completed
upload
one iteration completed
upload
one iteration completed
upload
one iteration completed
upload
one iteration completed
upload
one iteration completed
upload
one iteration completed
upload
one iteration completed
upload
one iteration completed
upload
one iteration completed
All upload complete
```

Expected output:

```
 cropped
   upload
   one iteration completed
  cropped
   upload
   one iteration completed
   .....
  All upload complete
```

Comment: You are using async.each which runs all operations in parallel. So async.waterfall([]) gets fired parallel for all items. You would need to use async.eachSeries to get what you expect where it will wait for each iteration.

Comment: please update with code

Comment: can you try changing async.each to async.eachSeries ? And let me know the result?

Comment: Let me check it

Comment: Thanks its worked

Answer (score 0):

Can you try `async.eachOfSeries` function? I doubt that `async.each` function runs the iteratee parallelly (as mentioned in docs), this must be causing the issue.